# Natural (business) keys naming conventions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

The name of the column should denote that it is a natural (business) key. I Haven't found any recommendations or good practices for this naming (e.g. columnName_NK, NKey_columnName, columnName_ID)?

Comment: Interesting question.  I could see this being useful for type 2 dimensions.

Comment: where I work we go with e.g. `MaterialID` vs. `MaterialKey`. The underscores in your proposal make it look like it was the index name instead of the column name.

Comment: We use Id as the entities Id (the natural key) and RecordId as the id of the row (surrogate id). I would say it doesn't really matter too much AS LONG AS YOU ARE CONSISTANT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference is to use BK at the end of the column name.

1. BK is not a very common combination in English language words, even less so at the end of the word.  This makes it easy to programmatically identify your business keys.
2. It is easily understood without additional documentation.
3. Adding it at the end allows the eyes to easily read the definition of the column (PersonBK vs BKPerson)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `ColumnNameIdentifier`, because we used to have surrogate IDs, which looked like `ColumnNameID`.